# run docker image of python project uploaded to docker hub

Tags: python, docker

**Run docker image of python project **
I have made a github workflow that would make a docker image of my django project and also I am able to pull the image from the docker hub but if I run the command
`docker run -p 8000:8000 image`
its not working
but if I run
`docker run -p 8000:8000 -it image bash`  
`insidebash# python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000`
it's working, how do I handle this command to runserver is there any file that I can write or yaml file that will contain the commands to run it in this style or am I doing something wrong

Comment: You probably need to add a CMD declarative at the end of your image to tell what service to run.

Comment: Thanks it worked, forgot to add the command in the file

Answer (score 1):

Create a Dockerfile with the folllwing content:

```
FROM image

CMD ["python", "manage.py", "runserver", "0.0.0.0:8000"]
```

Then, build the image:

```
docker build -t customimage .
```

And run the container:

```
docker run -p 8000:8000 customimage
```